# Rails 4 render partial form with a collection_select and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rendering, ujs

I'm trying to create a form that renders different partials based on the option selected in `collection_select`

Here is what I've developed:

```
#new.html.erb     
<%= form_for(@person) do |f| %> 
        <div class="field"> 
            <%= f.label "Person type" %><br>
            <%= f.collection_select :person_type, Reg.where(daw_tabla_id: 20), :idregtab, :reg_char, {:include_blank => true}, {:multiple => false, :id => "tipop", :data => {:remote => true}}  %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

The `collection_select` give me the options 0, 1, 2 ,3 and 4

Based on the option choice I want to render a `_form.html.erb` partial and then, the `_form1.html.erb` or `_form2.html.erb` ... with jquery or ajax..

render_js.js.erb

```
$.jQuery(function(){
$('#tipop').on('change',function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('#tipop').value;
  <%= j render 'form'%>
  switch (val) {
    case "1":
      return <%= j render 'formestudent'%>;
    case "2":
      return console.log("val 2");
    case "3":
      return console.log("valor 3");
    case "4":
      return console.log("valor 4");
    default:
      return console.log("default");
  }
});
```

});

Can anyone give me a clue about this ?